# callback within a timed loop

Tags: lua

I want to have a  timed loop that contains a callback function. The callback function should only be callable within the time period

```
function my_callback( )
    ....
end


setCallback("my_callback")

time_limit = os.time() + 20

while (os.time() < time_limit) do

 -- I want my_callback to be callable in this loop for 20 seconds only

end
```

What is a proper way to get this effect

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need but check out [lalarm](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lalarm) and [luasignal](https://github.com/doy/luasignal).